# Angular.js: Why does array element equal null only when using a factory?

Tags: javascript, angularjs

Trying to wrap my head around why this is not working. When I have my $http.get in my controller, I can convert the number stored in the JSON file to a array element like so:

```
$http.get('weapon.json').success(function(data) {
    $scope.weapons = data;

    for(i=0, len=$scope.weapons.length; i < len; i++){
        $scope.weapons[i].ele = $scope.elementType[$scope.weapons[i].ele];
    }
});
```

But when I try and move my $http.get into a factory, $scope.weapons[i].ele equal null instead of the array element.

```
.factory('WeaponData', function($http){
    return $http.get('weapon.json');
})

.controller('BL2Ctrl', function($scope,WeaponData) {
    WeaponData.success(function(data) {
        $scope.weapons = data;

        for(i=0, len=$scope.weapons.length; i < len; i++){
            $scope.weapons[i].ele = $scope.elementType[$scope.weapons[i].ele];
        }
    });
})
```

here is a [Plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/AzgSPL30GkuzfaY5v5z3) where it doesn't work

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that your controller is being instantiated 3 times. Therefore, its constructor is being run 3 times and the `data` returned from your `$http.get` is being updated 3 times (since you set up the `success` handler 3 times). After the first time, it has the values you are wanting; the 2, 3, and 3 are replaced with the respective objects from your `elementType` list. The problem is that the second and third times the `success` handler is called, the list is updated again, but `ele` attribute has already been overwritten. Therefore, it gets updated to `undefined` because there is no property of the `elementType` object which matches the key `[object Object]` (or whatever the string value ends up being). There are a few ways to solve this:

1. Create a larger factory and push the update to `weapon[i].ele` into the factory. http://plnkr.co/edit/CSv3ZRSL9K3bOcc9fcMJ
2. Use `elementType[weaponStats.ele]` in the view, rather than updating the model. http://plnkr.co/edit/UqVz88hVvNATO42A2Aew
3. Update a different attribute (e.g. `eleType`) instead of overwriting `ele`. This will prevent you from losing the value loaded from the JSON. (You'll still be updating the objects 3 times.) http://plnkr.co/edit/EqbXUT6gCthtGbC7VQHO

On a separate note, I noticed that you are binding the controller to one of the `<div>`s around the `ng-repeat`, but you also declare that the controller for the `weaponblock` directive is the same controller. This means you're redoing all of that work for each directive even though you don't need to. Here is a partial rewrite which splits up the single controller you had into 1 controller to set up the data and a separate controller to set up the functions for the directive: http://plnkr.co/edit/6NpcuZLJutdC9rtwhJXd

Comment: 1. Not sure how I would use weaponStats.ele in the factory. SOrry for the miss communication. The way I had it working before was with no factory service at all. Like this [Plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/erd0FcMqUZq1Qz5CzF1G)

Comment: 1. Not sure how I would use weaponStats.ele in the factory. SOrry for the miss communication. The way I had it working before was with no factory service at all. Like this [Plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/erd0FcMqUZq1Qz5CzF1G)    2. I tried this way before, but it breaks the select dropdown.    3. This works, but is it the most effective way? I was passing the whole elementType attribute that I wanted in the JSON, but I went with the number trying to fix another problem I had with the select for weaponStats.ele defaulting to blank in the view.

Comment: Yeah, I noticed the same problem with 3. That was actually caused by the problem I note at the bottom of my updated answer. Basically you were creating a new set of `elementType` objects that only one of your `weaponblock` directives could see. I added working examples for each of the options I discussed. I think that the first option is probably the best one; that's why I used it as the basis for my final update suggestion.

Comment: Thank you so much for such a thorough answer and multiple solutions!